# Simplelightbox not working with jQuery 3.4.1

Tags: jquery

I am having issues getting my Simplelightbox to work. I followed a tutorial from Traversy, but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Inside my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/simple-lightbox.min.css">
    <title>Simplelightbox Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/523/198/482/google-logo-google-search-google-play-google.jpg"><img src="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/523/198/482/google-logo-google-search-google-play-google.jpg" alt="photo"></a>
        <a href="https://chromeunboxed.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/GoogleAssistant-1200x550.png"><img src="https://chromeunboxed.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/GoogleAssistant-1200x550.png" alt="two"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        const $gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsIG6.png)

Comment: Please add a small demo for this with few images to show its not working. You can get `simple-lightbox.min.js` from https://cdnjs.com/.

Comment: You have an error in your script, instead of 
<script src="js/simple-lightbox.min.js""></script>

you should put
<script src="js/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>

Comment: I've created js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/5yx3pdeg/1/

Comment: @DenisOmerovic please provide your solution as an answer rather than a comment. So, the ticket could be closed and you get the credit for it

Comment: @DenisOmerovic hello Denis, I copied and pasted your Script tags and "const $gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();" but it still not working. The Script tags are inside my index.html file

Comment: @palaѕн hi i posted small demo. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Include scripts in your HTML file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/2.1.3/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/2.1.3/simple-lightbox.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/850602/pexels-photo-850602.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=photography-of-three-dogs-looking-up-850602.jpg&fm=jpg">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/850602/pexels-photo-850602.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=photography-of-three-dogs-looking-up-850602.jpg&fm=jpg" width="250" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/319975/pexels-photo-319975.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-animal-blur-breed-319975.jpg&fm=jpg">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/319975/pexels-photo-319975.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-animal-blur-breed-319975.jpg&fm=jpg" width="250" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Then just call the function in your JS file

```
$('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
```